# Optimize query, taking more time to execute

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have following simple query that I want to optimize:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name AS nam
FROM ghost a
WHERE a.name NOT 
IN (
SELECT ghost
FROM users
)
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
```

This query right now is taking 5sec to execute, because ghost table is having 1200 names record. Please if anybody having optimize way to execute this query, because I want to add more names also in ghost table, so it will be much larger than now. But if query is taking much time now then it will be hell situation for me if I add more records...

Below is the structure of both the tables:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why the random order?

Comment: Please add the table structure. Do you have any indexes defined? 1200 records is like nothing for a database.

Comment: Because needs to select names randomly from the table

Comment: Can you post an EXPLAIN of the select as well sp we can see the indexes it is using.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try rewriting it as a join, but the ORDER BY RAND() is going to hurt performance more

```
SELECT a.id, a.name AS nam
FROM ghost a
LEFT OUTER JOIN users b
ON a.name = b.ghost
WHERE b.ghost IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
```

Does the users table have an index on the ghost column?

To eliminate the order by RAND you could try something like this:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.name AS nam
FROM ghost a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT RAND( ) * ( MAX( z.id ) - MIN( z.id ) ) + MIN( z.id ) AS id
    FROM ghost z
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users y
    ON z.name = b.ghost
    WHERE y.ghost IS NULL
) r2
ON a.id >= r2.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users b
ON a.name = b.ghost
WHERE b.ghost IS NULL
ORDER BY a.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes Rand() function is taking much time...Any alternative for rand()

Comment: almost same time for both the queries...:(